# When I build a customized form controls base on AntD, the input addonBefore has some trouble

Tags: reactjs, antd

When I input something, render wrong things.
for example, I input 'a', the state is Object {test: 'a'};
the render is

It should render 'a' in input. But got 'bf_a'.

Here is the code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/wojkrmyzol

Comment: It's a problem with your handleAddon() logic. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do there? When you spread the props it already adds the bf_ to your input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code

`<Input value={this.state.data} addonBefore="bf_" onChange={this.handleDataChange} />`

---

instead of

```
`<Input value={this.state.data} {...this.props} onChange={this.handleDataChange} />`
```

fixed the issue try to explore in their source code what exactly is happening.
There might be some bug in the library as it also accepts prefix and suffix